# Detect misplaced form after restoring top and left from usersettings

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm storing the last position for each window.

Next time the user opens the window, the last position is restored.

If the user changes his screen (from dual screen to one screen) or just to a smaller resolution, the form is nowhere to be seen...

How can I detect this? I don't like to store user settings, depending on his environment.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from scratch, you want two settings to store the state of the window.  Let's call them Location (type Point, default = 0,0) and Size (type Size, default = 0, 0).  You want to save them when the window is resized, avoiding storing state if the window is minimized:

```
    protected override void OnResizeEnd(EventArgs e) {
        if (this.WindowState != FormWindowState.Minimized) {
            Properties.Settings.Default.Location = this.Location;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Size = this.Size;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
        base.OnResizeEnd(e);
    }
```

Restore the state in the form's OnLoad method.  You'll want to use Screen.FromPoint() to find the screen bounds back.  Add extra code to ensure the window doesn't get too large and locates properly when the screen has disappeared:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.Size != Size.Empty) {
            Screen scr = Screen.FromPoint(Properties.Settings.Default.Location);
            int width = Math.Min(Properties.Settings.Default.Size.Width, scr.WorkingArea.Width);
            int height = Math.Min(Properties.Settings.Default.Size.Height, scr.WorkingArea.Height);
            this.Size = new Size(width, height);
            if (scr.WorkingArea.Contains(Properties.Settings.Default.Location))
                this.Location = Properties.Settings.Default.Location;
            else this.Location = new Point(scr.Bounds.Left + (scr.Bounds.Width - width) / 2, 
                                           scr.Bounds.Top + (scr.Bounds.Height - height) / 2);
        }
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

Comment: works perfectly - thanks Hans. I didn't knew the WorkingArea property of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Bounds` property from [System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.primaryscreen.aspx) to see what the bounds of the screen is, compare that to the position/size of your form and compensate where needed.

To get at the bounds of other screens, use the `Screen.AllScreens` property on the `PrimaryScreen` property to gain access to other `Screen` objects representing multiple screens.

For example, this may be as simple as checking that the `Location` you want to change to is on an available screen:

```
foreach (var screen in Screen.AllScreens)
{
    if (screen.Bounds.Contains(this.Location))
    {
        return; // on a screen, so don't update location
    }
}
// not found on a screen, so assume screen was removed and move to the primary screen
this.Location = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Location;
```

You can, of course, make this more complicated by deciding which screen contains more of the form than any other (based on `Bounds`) and make a determination that way; but, without more details about exactly what you want, I can't suggest specifics.

Comment: But thats just the PrimaryScreen... i want to support muliple screens aswell.

Comment: `PrimaryScreen` is of type `Screen` which has an `AllScreens` Property to gain access to other `Screen` objects representing multiple screens.

Comment: yes, shortcut is Screen.AllScreens... i store a top and left. how can i detect, if the form is missplaced?